# Why are HashMaps not Semigroups, but Maps are?

Tags: scala, dictionary, hashmap, scalaz, liskov-substitution-principle

```
def foo(a: Map[String, Int], b: HashMap[String, Int]) {
  // okay
  val ab = a |+| b

  // value |+| is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String,Int]
  val ba = b |+| a
}
```

Why are HashMaps not Semigroups, but Maps are? Coming from an object-oriented background, I would have expected that a HashMap is every bit as capable as a Map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Semigroup` is invariant and there is no instance defined for specifically `HashMap`, just `Map`.  The invariance basically means that the `|+|` syntax cannot use the `Semigroup` instance for `Map` on a type which is inferred to be `HashMap`, even though `HashMap` is a subtype of `Map`.

In some cases, Scalaz typeclasses are needlessly invariant.  This is not one of those cases though.  Because of the signature of the `|+|` function, variance (either co- or contra-) wouldn't make much sense, and thus the typeclass is correct in its maximal generality.